# Returning Expression Lambda From Function Call Issue

Tags: c#

I need to have this function below, where if the enum value is C it just places Boolean true in the second lambda value instead of retrieving it from the User properties.

```
public static Expression<Func<User, bool>> IsValid(this Component.ValueEnum component)
{
    return component switch
    {
        Component.ValueEnum.A => u:User => u.token.x.IsValid,
        Component.ValueEnum.B => u:User => u.token.y.IsValid,
        Component.ValueEnum.C => u:User => true,                                            
        _ => throw new ArgumentException($"unrecognized component {component}")
    };
}
```

However, when I attempt this it throws exception with:

System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for u => True

What am I doing wrong?  Is it possible?

UPDATE 1:

Ok, I see that this line is not possible:

Component.ValueEnum.C => u:User => true

The resulting Lambda is being used to filter a collection of User and this is an illegal operation.

Comment: Can you show/describe how this method is being used? And where is the exception bring thrown from? Is it for a mongodb mapping?

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, I removed Expression as return type. If all you need inside is a lamda function that takes in a `User` and returns a `bool` directly or using the `User`, following changes to code might help you -

```
public static Func<User, bool> IsValid(this Component.ValueEnum component)
{
    return component switch
    {
        Component.ValueEnum.A => (User u) => u.token.x.IsValid,
        Component.ValueEnum.B => (User u) => u.token.y.IsValid,
        Component.ValueEnum.C => (User u) => true,                                            
        _ => throw new ArgumentException($"unrecognized component {component}")
    };
}
```